# Power Query: How to assemble list of files from multiple directories (Folder.Files, Table.Combine)

Tags: powerquery

I'd like to load a list of files from multiple different folders and merge them all into one table.

Just going by the documentation, I thought this code should work:

```
let
    Source1 = Folder.Files("folder path 1"),
    Source2 = Folder.Files("folder path 2"),
    Appended = Table.Combine(Source1,Source2)
in
    Appended
```

...but this is giving me the error: "2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 1"

That would make it seem like I am very close, but I have been trying to get this syntax right for quite a while and google isn't doing much for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor typo (note the braces around tables in combine statement):

```
let
    Source1 = Folder.Files("folder path 1"),
    Source2 = Folder.Files("folder path 2"),
    Appended = Table.Combine({Source1,Source2})
in
    Appended
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260748.aspx